# Compile same piece of source code with different Instruction Set Architecture

Tags: assembly, compilation, instruction-set

OK, as far as I understand there are many different types of ISA for different CPUs, such as x86, MIPS, etc. When the compiler compile the source code (C++/JAVA) in different ISA environments, the assembly code generated will be different as well. And then, I wonder whether the binary machine code generated will be different as well or just the same???? My wild guess is that the binary code generated will be the same, otherwise how can different CPU run the same piece of exe file on different computers?? I wonder whether my hypothesis is correct or not. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: _"otherwise how can different CPU run the same piece of exe file on different computers??"_ What makes you think that they can? A Raspberry PI can't run an executable built for an x86/Windows-based PC (or vice versa). Not without some kind of emulator at least. If you're talking about two x86-based PCs (running the same type of OS) then the simple answer is that they share the same CPU architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary code generated for different CPUs is different. One example C program:

```
int a;

int b(int c)
{
    return a+c;
}
```

Compiled with the GCC compiler for 32-bit x86:

```
8b 44 24 04             // mov    0x4(%esp), %eax
03 05 xx xx xx xx       // add    a, %eax
c3                      // ret
```

The same program compiled with the GCC compiler for MIPS:

```
3c 1c xx xx 27 9c xx xx  // la      gp, GOT  - actually 2 instructions!
8f 82 xx xx 00 00 00 00  // la      v0, a    - actually 2 instructions!
8c 42 00 00              // lw      v0,0(v0)
03 e0 00 08              // jr      ra
00 44 10 21              // addu    v0, v0, a0
```

Of course the .exe file for x86 will not work on MIPS and vice versa!

An exception to this are Java and .NET exectuables:

These types executables contain a special type of code which can neither be executed by x86 nor by MIPS, ARM or PPC. However this code is designed in a way that it can easiely be translated into machine-dependent code.

When you execute a .NET .exe file on Windows the first time the CPU-independent code in the .exe file will be translated into x86-only (or ARM-only or whatever) code and the "translated" variant will be stored in a temporary directory. The file from the temporary directory will actually be executed.

Java works similar but a bit more complicated...